# Openstack Pike installation Neutron Compute could not be found error

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon

Hi I am new to Openstack I have installed the OpenStack Pike version (Keystone, Glance, Nova, Neutron, Horizon) with two ubuntu 16.04 VM (Controller and Compute Node) and added  ICMP, SSH  ports to security group but I could not able ping the instance ip, This is the link for the Doc https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/openstack-services.html
For neutron I have choose self-service networks

This is My Console Log of the Instance

```
NOCHANGE: partition 1 is size 10458315. it cannot be grown
info: initramfs loading root from /dev/vda1
info: /etc/init.d/rc.sysinit: up at 5.09
info: container: none
Starting logging: OK
modprobe: module virtio_blk not found in modules.dep
modprobe: module virtio_net not found in modules.dep
WARN: /etc/rc3.d/S10-load-modules failed
Initializing random number generator... done.
Starting acpid: OK
cirros-ds 'local' up at 7.70
no results found for mode=local. up 8.31. searched: nocloud configdrive ec2
Starting network...
udhcpc (v1.20.1) started
Sending discover...
Sending select for 10.0.0.11...
Lease of 10.0.0.11 obtained, lease time 86400
route: SIOCADDRT: File exists
WARN: failed: route add -net "0.0.0.0/0" gw "10.0.0.1"
cirros-ds 'net' up at 9.71
checking http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/instance-id
failed 1/20: up 9.90. request failed
failed 2/20: up 14.06. request failed
failed 3/20: up 20.58. request failed
failed 4/20: up 32.71. request failed
failed 5/20: up 35.68. request failed
failed 6/20: up 47.78. request failed
failed 7/20: up 50.76. request failed
failed 8/20: up 53.40. request failed
failed 9/20: up 56.17. request failed
failed 10/20: up 58.86. request failed
failed 11/20: up 63.43. request failed
failed 12/20: up 66.60. request failed
failed 13/20: up 78.80. request failed
failed 14/20: up 81.63. request failed
failed 15/20: up 84.49. request failed
failed 16/20: up 87.27. request failed
failed 17/20: up 89.93. request failed
failed 18/20: up 92.73. request failed
failed 19/20: up 95.79. request failed
failed 20/20: up 98.56. request failed
failed to read iid from metadata. tried 20
no results found for mode=net. up 101.26. searched: nocloud configdrive ec2
failed to get instance-id of datasource
Top of dropbear init script
Starting dropbear sshd: failed to get instance-id of datasource
WARN: generating key of type ecdsa failed!
OK
```

This is my **neutron-l3-agent.log** (Compute Node)

```
2018-07-02 18:22:35.009 13819 INFO neutron.common.config [-] Logging enabled!
2018-07-02 18:22:35.010 13819 INFO neutron.common.config [-] /usr/bin/neutron-l3-agent version 11.0.3
2018-07-02 18:22:35.329 13819 ERROR neutron.agent.l3.agent [-] An interface driver must be specified
```

This is my **neutron-linuxbridge-agent.log** (Compute Node)

```
2018-07-02 18:24:25.186 7298 INFO neutron.agent.securitygroups_rpc [req-85444d73-0a1f-49df-ba25-98c0edc8d64d - - - - -] Security group member updated [u'957d8ed4-dba5-4cf5-b6df-0c7c044e4376']
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-85444d73-0a1f-49df-ba25-98c0edc8d64d - - - - -] Error occurred while removing port tapac1db012-e4: RemoteError: Remote error: AgentNotFoundByTypeHost Agent with agent_type=L3 agent and host=Compute could not be found
[u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 160, in _process_incoming\n    res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 213, in dispatch\n    return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 183, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/rpc.py", line 234, in update_device_down\n    n_const.PORT_STATUS_DOWN, host)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/rpc.py", line 331, in notify_l2pop_port_wiring\n    l2pop_driver.obj.update_port_down(port_context)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/l2pop/mech_driver.py", line 253, in update_port_down\n    admin_context, agent_host, [port[\'device_id\']]):\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/db/l3_agentschedulers_db.py", line 303, in list_router_ids_on_host\n    context, constants.AGENT_TYPE_L3, host)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/db/agents_db.py", line 291, in _get_agent_by_type_and_host\n    host=host)\n', u'AgentNotFoundByTypeHost: Agent with agent_type=L3 agent and host=Compute could not be found\n'].
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/agent/_common_agent.py", line 337, in treat_devices_removed
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     cfg.CONF.host)
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/agent/rpc.py", line 139, in update_device_down
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     agent_id=agent_id, host=host)
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/common/rpc.py", line 162, in call
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     return self._original_context.call(ctxt, method, **kwargs)
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py", line 169, in call
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     retry=self.retry)
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line 123, in _send
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     timeout=timeout, retry=retry)
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 578, in send
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     retry=retry)
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 569, in _send
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     raise result
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent RemoteError: Remote error: AgentNotFoundByTypeHost Agent with agent_type=L3 agent and host=Compute could not be found
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 160, in _process_incoming\n    res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 213, in dispatch\n    return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 183, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/rpc.py", line 234, in update_device_down\n    n_const.PORT_STATUS_DOWN, host)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/rpc.py", line 331, in notify_l2pop_port_wiring\n    l2pop_driver.obj.update_port_down(port_context)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/l2pop/mech_driver.py", line 253, in update_port_down\n    admin_context, agent_host, [port[\'device_id\']]):\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/db/l3_agentschedulers_db.py", line 303, in list_router_ids_on_host\n    context, constants.AGENT_TYPE_L3, host)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/db/agents_db.py", line 291, in _get_agent_by_type_and_host\n    host=host)\n', u'AgentNotFoundByTypeHost: Agent with agent_type=L3 agent and host=Compute could not be found\n'].
2018-07-02 18:24:25.364 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent 
2018-07-02 18:24:25.366 7298 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-85444d73-0a1f-49df-ba25-98c0edc8d64d - - - - -] Attachment tapac454bed-28 removed
2018-07-02 18:24:25.810 7298 INFO neutron.agent.securitygroups_rpc [req-85444d73-0a1f-49df-ba25-98c0edc8d64d - - - - -] Security group member updated [u'957d8ed4-dba5-4cf5-b6df-0c7c044e4376']
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-85444d73-0a1f-49df-ba25-98c0edc8d64d - - - - -] Error occurred while removing port tapac454bed-28: RemoteError: Remote error: AgentNotFoundByTypeHost Agent with agent_type=L3 agent and host=Compute could not be found
[u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 160, in _process_incoming\n    res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 213, in dispatch\n    return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 183, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/rpc.py", line 234, in update_device_down\n    n_const.PORT_STATUS_DOWN, host)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/rpc.py", line 331, in notify_l2pop_port_wiring\n    l2pop_driver.obj.update_port_down(port_context)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/l2pop/mech_driver.py", line 253, in update_port_down\n    admin_context, agent_host, [port[\'device_id\']]):\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/db/l3_agentschedulers_db.py", line 303, in list_router_ids_on_host\n    context, constants.AGENT_TYPE_L3, host)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/db/agents_db.py", line 291, in _get_agent_by_type_and_host\n    host=host)\n', u'AgentNotFoundByTypeHost: Agent with agent_type=L3 agent and host=Compute could not be found\n'].
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/agent/_common_agent.py", line 337, in treat_devices_removed
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     cfg.CONF.host)
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/agent/rpc.py", line 139, in update_device_down
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     agent_id=agent_id, host=host)
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/common/rpc.py", line 162, in call
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     return self._original_context.call(ctxt, method, **kwargs)
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py", line 169, in call
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     retry=self.retry)
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line 123, in _send
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     timeout=timeout, retry=retry)
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 578, in send
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     retry=retry)
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 569, in _send
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     raise result
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent RemoteError: Remote error: AgentNotFoundByTypeHost Agent with agent_type=L3 agent and host=Compute could not be found
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 160, in _process_incoming\n    res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 213, in dispatch\n    return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 183, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/rpc.py", line 234, in update_device_down\n    n_const.PORT_STATUS_DOWN, host)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/rpc.py", line 331, in notify_l2pop_port_wiring\n    l2pop_driver.obj.update_port_down(port_context)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/l2pop/mech_driver.py", line 253, in update_port_down\n    admin_context, agent_host, [port[\'device_id\']]):\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/db/l3_agentschedulers_db.py", line 303, in list_router_ids_on_host\n    context, constants.AGENT_TYPE_L3, host)\n', u'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/db/agents_db.py", line 291, in _get_agent_by_type_and_host\n    host=host)\n', u'AgentNotFoundByTypeHost: Agent with agent_type=L3 agent and host=Compute could not be found\n'].
2018-07-02 18:24:26.215 7298 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent
```

Comment: **Compute could not be found** Add this kind of text into your title so that the question/answers become easier to be followed in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `/etc/neutron/neutron.conf` on both controller and all of the compute nodes (under **[oslo_concurrency]** section):

> lock_path = /var/lib/neutron/tmp

Comment: The **openstack** document lacks a lot of configuration steps. I have also managed to add those configurations (missing from the official guide)

Comment: Thanks, Malik Asif.